# Find elements with class 'x', ignore those with class 'x' and another class

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenuim with Javascript to wite my test. The DOM has 4 elements:

`<input class="hidden-element xyz">`, `<input class="hidden-element xyz">`, `<input class="xyz">`, and  `<input class="xyz">`

I would like to find the elements with only the `xyz` class, not the ones with `hidden-element` and `xyz`. When I say:

```
if (driver.findElements({css: 'section[title="custom"] > input.xyz'})) {
  driver.findElements({css: 'section[title="custom"] > input.xyz'}).then(function(inputs) {
    for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
      inputs[i].sendKeys('Input Text');
    }
  });
}
```

It will pull all 4 elements, try to fill in the hidden elements, and break the test. I've tried:

```
if (driver.findElements({css: 'section[title="custom"] > input.xyz'}) && !driver.findElements({css: 'section[title="custom"] > input.hidden-element'})) {
  driver.findElements({css: 'section[title="custom"] > input.xyz'}).then(function(inputs) {
    for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
      inputs[i].sendKeys('Input Text');
    }
  });
}
```

But that doesn't work either. I've been playing around with different variations of this as well, but to no avail. It seems like something simple, but I am having a difficult time honing in on the solution. Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your selector should be:

```
.xyz:not(.hidden-elem)
```

This is because `A and not(A and B)` effectively pours down to `A and not B`

Edit: seems like you had already figured out the logic

Comment: This is just what I was looking for! Perfect

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest, if there are potentially multiple other class-names to filter out:

```
// define the function, and its arguments:
function uniquelyClassed (arr, cName) {
  // arr: Array of elements to filter,
  // cName: String, the class-name you wish
  // to filter by

  // checking that the passed Array is in fact
  // an Array:
  if (arr instanceof Array) {

    // filtering the passed Array,
    // 'n' is the array-element of the
    // Array over which we're iterating:
    return arr.filter(function (n) {

      // checking that there is one class-name,
      // and that the class-list contains the
      // passed-in class-name:
      return n.classList.length === 1 && n.classList.contains(cName);
    });
  }
}

// finding the <input> elements in the document:
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('input'),

    // converting the HTMLCollection into an Array,
    // using Array.prototype.slice():
    elementsArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(elements, 0),

    // calling the function to find the elements with the
    // unique class name:
    uniquelyXYZ = uniquelyClassed(elementsArray, 'xyz');

// iterating over the Array using forEach():    
uniquelyXYZ.forEach(function (el) {

  // adding the 'found' class-name to the
  // element (to visibly show the found elements):
  el.classList.add('found');
});
```

```js
function uniquelyClassed (arr, cName) {
  if (arr instanceof Array) {
  return arr.filter(function (n) {
    return n.classList.length === 1 && n.classList.contains(cName);
  });
  }
}

var elements = document.querySelectorAll('input'),
    elementsArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(elements, 0),
    uniquelyXYZ = uniquelyClassed(elementsArray, 'xyz');

uniquelyXYZ.forEach(function (el) {
  el.classList.add('found');
});
```

```css
input {
  margin: 0 0 0.5em 0;
  display: block;
}
.found {
  border-color: limegreen;
}
```

```html
<input class="hidden-element xyz">
<input class="hidden-element xyz">
<input class="xyz">
<input class="xyz">
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/zadfc45v/).

References:

- [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).
- [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).
- [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).
- [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof).